# Maximum length of lines

Tags: c, character

I am wondering if there is a limit for the length of a line (Characters per line) in a code written in C, something similar to the Fortran 72 (or 80 including all) limit. I know that style guides usually point towards 80 for readability purposes but I want to know if there is a real limit for C as it does happens for Fortran.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Source line length limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519738/source-line-length-limit)

Comment: fwiw limit in Fortran is 132: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990119/why-is-maximum-single-line-length-limited-to-132-characters-in-fortran-standard

Comment: C and C++ are two seperate languages with their own set of rules. Please dont tag both unless the question is about interoperation of the two languages.

Comment: @MathewHD It does answer it for C++, so I changed the question to only include C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [C11 5.2.4.1 Translation Limits](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1):

> The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits:
>
> - [...]
> - 4095 characters in a logical source line

Any C compiler should be able to process **at least** lines with 4095 characters. Nowadays compilers have no upper limit - it is effectively constrained by available memory.

As an example [gcc documentation Implementation Limits](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-limits.html) states:

> - Number of characters on a logical source line.
>
> The C standard requires a minimum of 4096 be permitted. CPP places no limits on this, but you may get incorrect column numbers reported in diagnostics for lines longer than 65,535 characters.